# System hang-up while installing LTS 20.04 64 bit via USB-Flash over Win10 on HP-ENVY desktop

Tags: partitioning, root, lvm, ext4, anacron

System hangs-up while installing LTS 20.04 64bit via USB-Flash over Win10 on HP-ENVY desktop. (Minimum install)

Been running for over 12 hours, stuck on the following...

Creating ext4 file system for / in partition #1 of LVM VG vgubuntu, LV root...

(Anacron jobs run and succeed once an hour.)

**Keep waiting or Power-off and start over?**

BTW: system-info link now at **https://termbin.com/s4hy**

Comment: Over 12 hours is way too long time to wait. Turn it off and try again. But I think you should also tell us details about the **computer** (brand name and model), the **version/flavour** of Ubuntu, the **tool** to put it from the iso file to the USB flash drive. -- Did you check with `sha256sum` that the downloaded iso file is good? Does the live system (booted from USB into 'Try Ubuntu') work well? -- If possible, please tell us more details by running the [`system-info` script by the Ubuntu Forums](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Yes, booting from USB works OK. I'll power-off, re-try, and provide more info if same situation occurs.

Comment: Powered-off, rebooted again from USB into "Try Ubuntu" OK. Selected "Install 20.04.4 LTS" again with minimal install without downloading updates, erase disk with no advanced features, no security key. Still hangs while creating ext4 file sys. Ran the sys-info. How do I attach it here?

Comment: Let it upload the result to a pastebin. You will get that option after existing the viewer `less` by pressing the 'q' key. Then you can edit your original question to add a link to that pastebin (and write a comment telling me and others to have a look at it).

Comment: Thanks again. system-info link now at https://termbin.com/s4hy

Comment: From the pastebin data, it seems to me, that the *live* system works well. And there is a partition `/dev/sda2` where the installer should be able to install Ubuntu. Since you have only a small partition with Windows RE tools, `/dev/sda2`, I would suggest that you let the installer use the whole drive (and overwrite everything) next time you try. Furthermore, it can cause problems during installation with nvidia graphics, and you could try with the boot option `nomodeset`, but because your live system works well, my first guess is that it is not the problem.

Comment: Is your SATA controller set in RAID mode? You can check that in the BIOS menu system, and maybe change it to AHCI mode.

Comment: Changed to AHCI. Re-trying same install. Failed to mount SCSI1 partition#1(sda). It's attempting now to format partition#1 of SCSI as ESP and partition#2 as ext4. Will give it an hour...

Comment: Nope, still hangs. Need help selecting Partition Table options to define root file sys and letting the installation take the whole drive. (Too many options)

Comment: I try to start a chat room ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137847/discussion-between-sudodus-and-branlon).

Comment: I looked at your 'system-info' report. susdous asked if I could come here and help you... I wrote that script, and sudodus is a contributor... I also am a certified HP, Dell, and Lenovo Onsite Warranty Service Technician. Go into your BIOS Settings, SATA Mode and change your disk access mode from RAID mode to AHCI mode.  The RAID Mode of that BIOS only works with Windows OS's... sudodus saw that (in the Storage Controller section) about 4 comments previous to this. That is why is hangs at that part of the installer. Linux uses AHCI...

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the switch to AHCI was made. The Windows root partition was deleted and a new one created. The install then completed OK.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the switch to AHCI was made. The Windows root partition was deleted and a new one created. The install then completed OK.